# Change fixed background image on specific divs on it

Tags: html, jquery, css, css-animations, css-transitions

As I'm trying to make a "our story" section, when I scroll, the divs on it move up and the background picture changes when the specific div comes in the center. I want a fixed background image. When the div moves to the middle, the background picture may be changed with ease. Background image and div are related.

I'm still learning how to style, I can't create it correctly.

I've included a reference link so you can see what I'm aiming for.

Reference: https://webflow.com/made-in-webflow/website/Change-Background-Image-on-Scroll

```css
.parent {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/1080/1920);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  height: 300vh;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.div1{
  background-color: aqua;
  height: 50vh;
  margin-top: 90vh;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 90px auto

}

.div2{
  background-color: skyblue;
  height: 50vh;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 90px auto
}

.div3{
  background-color: grey;
  height: 50vh;
  margin-top: 90vh;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 90px auto

}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="div1" >
Content about desert
</div>

<div class="div2" >
Content about mountains
</div>

<div class="div3" >
Content about birds
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below is a rough example of how you might do it.  It should give you a starter to experiment with, and things to lookup on the WWW.

```js
var sections;
const backgrounds = [
"url(https://i.picsum.photos/id/604/1080/1920.jpg?hmac=ZGdArZ8jNmfX3SDYlQMsYeGsKy6b_1uBH2WGFt3wYzk)",
"url(https://i.picsum.photos/id/301/1080/1920.jpg?hmac=7cyfS0iaSux6TVm9Wnkg4vtXIWyg_YyhhWYHM6yUTnE)",
"url(https://i.picsum.photos/id/155/1080/1920.jpg?hmac=UZT1atpRomcjj2ijIjwR9C3DY0xtD4On3m5XMNLak6o)"
];
var parent;
var bottomOffset;
function getViewScrollingElements() {
    parent = document.getElementById("parent");
    sections = document.getElementsByClassName("section");
    bottomOffset = window.getComputedStyle(parent).getPropertyValue("height");
    bottomOffset = parseInt(bottomOffset.substr(0, bottomOffset.length - 2)) / 3;
    //  Do first check before a scroll could have occured
   checkInView();
}
function checkInView () {
    var boundingRect;
    for ( var i = 0; i < sections.length; i++ ) {
        //  Get the extremities of the div
        boundingRect = sections[i].getBoundingClientRect();
        //  Are the div's extremities in view
        if ( boundingRect.top < window.innerHeight && boundingRect.bottom >= bottomOffset ) {
            parent.style.backgroundImage = backgrounds[i];
            break;  //  Only want one at a time
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.background {
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.parent {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.section {
  height: 70vh;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 90px auto;
  opacity: 85%;
}

.section:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-color: aqua;
}

.section:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: skyblue;
}

.section:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<body onLoad="getViewScrollingElements()">
<div class="background"></div>
<div id="parent" class="parent" onScroll="checkInView()">
    <div class="section">
        Content about desert
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        Content about mountains
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        Content about birds
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

It does not like iframes as is so will not run properly in SOs fiddler, but does work in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: The backrground image is not showing in the snippet

Comment: The background-image is not changing when the second div comes in middle

Comment: 'Not showing in snippet': Yes. That is due to the images failing a security protocol when  in an iframe. But it will run otherwise.

Comment: 'Comes into the middle': Quite possibly. You will need to adjust the formulas in the if statement checking if the element is in view. You may even need to initialise it differently depending on screen heights and element heights. If each section is a different height you will need to do a separate  calculation for each section.

Comment: The coded is example is a rough example.

Comment: Okay i got it. Can you help me with this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74522710/get-scroll-event-on-a-section-rather-than-on-body